# How to trigger a NavigationLink programmatically on appear

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to trigger a NavigationLink programmatically on appear but in all cases the destination view pops immediately after appearing `(iOS 13.3.1, Xcode 11.3.1)`.

The setup is as follows: ContentView has a NavigationLink to DetailView1 which in turn has a NavigationLink to DetailView2. I would like the NavigationLink in DetailView1 to be triggered automatically when the DetailView1 first loads (in my actual code this would be based on a condition, but this is irrelevant here).

This is the basic code (without automatic behaviour):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView1()) {
                Text("Open Detail View 1")
            }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("ContentView"))
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView1: View {
@State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView2(), isActive: $isActive) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            Button ("Open Detail View 2") {
                self.isActive = true
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail View 1"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct DetailView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Detail View 2")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail View 2"), displayMode: .inline)
    } 
}
```

My first approach was to set `isActive` to true at its declaration in DetailView1:

```
@State private var isActive = true
```

As expected, the NavigationLink is triggered, but DetailView2 is popped immediately after appearing.

I also (alternatively) tried to set `isActive` to true in within `.onAppear`

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail View 1"), displayMode: .inline)
.onAppear(){
    self.isActive = true
}
```

The result however is the same.

What actually worked was delaying setting `isActive` to true by at least 0.75 seconds, which in my opinion is not an acceptable workaround.

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail View 1"), displayMode: .inline)
.onAppear(){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75) {
        self.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or is there a way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: what does it mean "on load" ??

Comment: @user3441734 Sorry, I meant "on appear" as stated in the question title. I have edited the question text to correct it now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 works properly using `.toggle()`, like below

```swift
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail View 1"), displayMode: .inline)
.onAppear {
    self.isActive.toggle()
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Would you know how .toggle() actually solves this issue?